# Find a duplicate in an extremely large data set

Tags: java, algorithm, stream, hashmap, large-data

Recently, I was asked the following question in an interview.

Q : **Given a N integers, only one of which is a duplicate, find that duplicate number.**

I answered with a solution that had the numbers stored in a hashmap and finding duplicates by checking for the existence of a key.

He then followed it up with **What if the data set is very large, so large that you cannot store it in memory, like a continuous stream?**

That kinda stumped me. Can someone suggest some answers? Also, are there any more efficient solutions other than hashmaps for the original question ?

TIA

Comment: " Can someone suggest some answers? Also, are there any more efficient solutions other than hashmaps for the original question ?" is not a suitable question for StackOverflow. It's an interesting question, but it's more suitable to a discussion forum than a Q&A site. See [help]. That said, have you though about storing one bit for each number, and checking if the bit is already set? That way you can keep record on an amount of numbers equal to 8 time the number of bytes of available free memory. `java.util.BitSet` supports *2^31-1* numbers but you can build something that supports even more.

Comment: a Map is not really suitable

Comment: Since we are given that there would be exactly one duplicate, I believe we can exit the program the moment we see the duplicate (notwithstanding the fact that there may be more numbers in the stream), right?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade Sure but the point is how do you know that number is duplicate...

Comment: @shole, just trying to clarify the requirements. This is an interview question, so one should ask clarifying questions.

Answer (score 2):

How large or small are those integers? If it's certain all the integers fall within 2^30-1 to -2^30, or a smaller range, try java.util.BitSet. 
2^31 bits = 2^28 bytes ~ 2^8 mega bytes = 256 mega bytes. This is small enough to be stored in memory for ordinary notebook computers.

Suppose the integers fall within 2^30-1 to -2^30, the method is simple; for each integer i in the large data set, set j = i + 2^30 first, and check if bitSet.get(j) is true, if true, the duplicate number is i, else invoke bitSet.set(j, true) and continue until the duplicate is found. It's similar if the integers fall within 0 to 2^31 -1.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("a.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String line = null;
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet((1<<31)- 1);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(line);
            boolean v = bitSet.get(i);
            if (v){
                System.out.println("the duplicate is " + i);
                break;
            }else{
                bitSet.set(i);
            }

        }
        reader.close();
```

And if the range is slightly larger, like 0 to 2^34 - 1, one tryable idea is to copy paste the java.util.BitSet class and made some modification it to create a slightly different one; one long[] array can store maximally ((2^31 - 1) * 2^6 - 1) bits. Ordinary computer can still afford 2G memory for an object.

If the range is larger or this duplication finding module cannot take much memory, refer to questions in the comments above like [Algorithm for detecting duplicates in a dataset which is too large to be completely loaded into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415070/algorithm-for-detecting-duplicates-in-a-dataset-which-is-too-large-to-be-complet)